# asp.net web form C# Streamreader can't find the text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

Trying to make a silly web form that keeps some small information in a text file inside a "data" folder. The code is:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("data/FeatureList.txt"));
String FileText = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
sr.Close();
```

Getting an exception:
    Could not find file 'C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2\data\FeatureList.txt'.

And, naturally, the file is there right in the specified folder.

Perhaps I have a permission error and IIS can't read the folder or file? Maybe I need to tell Visual Studio 2013 something about this folder? I haven't played with one of these asp.net programs in a while, not since... Well, a couple years ago I made a web page that reads text files and adds captions to displayed photos.

Comment: This might be a permissions issue. Check this out: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-setting-folder-permissions-6-of-12

Comment: What do you get for "bool exists = File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2\data\FeatureList.txt");" ?

Comment: if you paste this in windows explorer do you open the file? C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2\data\FeatureList.txt

Comment: bool exists = File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2\data\FeatureList.txt"); Gives me a false. If I paste it in windows explorer, it opens notepad and shows me the data in the file.

Comment: It could be a permissions problem as Pathachiever11 suggests. When I look at the permissions for that folder, I see only users SYSTEM, me and Administrators (Chessie\Administrators).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) , it is a good method to get a valid path

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), @"data/FeatureList.txt"));
String FileText = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
sr.Close();
```

Comment: It is indeed good to use `Path.Combine`. However PO mentioned that the file path is correct (from the exception).

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
string path = (string.Format("{0}\\{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"\data\FeatureList.txt));
```

Comment: Well, now I have several ways to get the same file not found exception.